How to run Docker without sudo on Ubuntu Linux?
I am only posting because i tried all solutions i found. I have not tried to change the permissions of /var/run/docker.sock which people have been saying is a security issue.
I tried adding my $USER to a docker group.
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER

After which I tried each method - log out & log in, reboot, newgrp docker, sudo systemctl restart docker, sudo service docker restart.
None of these solutions work for me.
I don't know if it helps but the docker service in htop runs as /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock.
I really need to run docker without sudo so i can attach my container to my vscode session.

What does groups say? Also this should probably be posted on https://superuser.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/

If you mean the output of cat /etc/group | grep docker - It is docker:x:999:<myuser>,<someoneelse>. fyi I share this cpu with a few others.
